# Possible to install ubuntu-desktop and then boot to no GUI

Tags: server, gui

I've installed Ubuntu Server. I'd like to add the GUI with ubuntu-desktop package, but if I do that can I still get the no-gui server interface as the default? What I basically need is the no-gui and the ability to start a gui when needed. Possible?