# Customize Ubuntu Server to load a minimal desktop only when needed

Tags: server, package-management, customization

I would like to have an install with:

1. Ubuntu Desktop with no additional applications or games
2. Graphical interface only when I manually run 'startx'

I am using Ubuntu server and would like a GUI, but do not want all of the additional desktop applications and games. (I'm using it with CLI mode.)

Comment: Thanks alot guys , i am new here so i was shocked thats someone changed my ? ...Thanks again thats wt i was asking

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/74645/possible-to-install-ubuntu-desktop-and-then-boot-to-no-gui

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did exactly this myself using:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop --no-install-recommends
```

Keep in mind that this will give you the bare minimum for a graphical desktop and will probably enable `lightdm` at startup. You can correct this by setting the kernel to boot to text mode:

1. Open a terminal and run:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/default/grub
   ```
2. Change the line that reads:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="splash quiet"
   ```

   to:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text"
   ```
3. Run:

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```
4. Restart.

---

**Edit:** Hmmm... that doesn't seem to be working. Probably you should just remove the `lightdm` package.

Comment: Can you explain how to do that good Mr. Penguin? :P

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/74645/possible-to-install-ubuntu-desktop-and-then-boot-to-no-gui  (working)

Answer (score 1):

See the [Server GUI](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ServerGUI) documentation for how to do this. Before installing a GUI on an Ubuntu Server system, please take note of the good reasons given there for *not* to install or run GUI's on production servers.

On any Ubuntu system with a display manager installed (which provides graphical login), you can disable graphical login (requiring a user to run `startx` to start X11) using [these instructions](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1573037). However, since GDM is replaced with LightDM in Oneiric (though you can still install and use GDM if you want), you should run `sudo service lightdm start` instead of `sudo service gdm start` if you're on Ubuntu 11.10 (or later, as more releases come out).