# How do I boot directly into a user's xterm?

Tags: auto-login, xterm

04 64bit and user called 'ubuntu'

How do I boot my system into ubuntu user's xterm without loading gnome-desktop and prompting for password?

I have tried hacking grub, but it always asks me for password, and bash profile cant load correctly, running `startx xterm` never loads bash, thanks in adv.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Possible to install ubuntu-desktop and then boot to no GUI](http://askubuntu.com/questions/74645/possible-to-install-ubuntu-desktop-and-then-boot-to-no-gui)

Comment: @izx A plain xterm session is not the same as a virtual console. A plain xterm session *is* a GUI, albeit a very basic one.

Answer (score 0):

So, you do not mean an xterm, but a command prompt without a GUI ?

Should work like that:
[Possible to install ubuntu-desktop and then boot to no GUI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74645/possible-to-install-ubuntu-desktop-and-then-boot-to-no-gui)

Comment: i do mean `xterm`, and I found a temporary solution by modifying /usr/share/xsession/ubuntu.desktop